# VSCode deletes my Go imports after I save the file

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am making a package manager for my own programming language [for more info](https://github.com/zplusfour/aardvark).

And I am working on the package manager on VSCode, I want to use `json` and `net/http`, then every Go developer should do:

```golang
import (
    "json"
    "net/http"
)
```

Image:

[image]

OK! But after I save the file:

[image]

I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_unused, https://golang.org/doc/faq#unused_variables_and_imports,

Comment: The Go extension will auto format on save. Auto formatting deletes unused imports. When you actually use them on your code, they won't be deleted.

Comment: Note that if you use `goimports` it will automatically try to add missing imports. So you can just use e.g. `json.Marshal()` in the code and `goimports` will add the "json" import automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You dont use it in the code so it deleted. Read more about [goimports](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports)